# Changing the value of ng-model bound html element using jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a long form with select boxes, text , number type input etc. What I wish is that when the user clicks the submit button of the form, we check which fields are currently empty and then fill those fields with dummy values so that when I finally read values i get correct scope vars values.

I am checking if the fields are empty using jQuery and then populate those fields using jQuery.

What happens is that though the fields get populated, the scope vars value does not change...How do I change this???

Here is a fiddle:[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/LDQPA/)

What I want is that here on clicking 'Click', as the input reads bhumiak, so should `<h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>`

How to do this?

Comment: Have you considered doing this in angular instead of jquery?

Comment: As @lucuma suggested, the correct way of doing this is to use the infrastructure provided by AnuglarJS. 

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as lucuma already mentioned, you shouldn't do this with jQuery but instead do it the angular way.

Angular already can fill the output string by itself with no additional code, something like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="na" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here"/>
    <input type="button" value="click" ng-click="myClick()"/>
    <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
</div>
```

Look into this fiddle, I made an example: http://jsfiddle.net/marcorinck/zYyLf/

Yes, you can use a call to $apply when its needed (especially in directives) but first you should give $apply a function parameter and second you should make changes in this function which angularJS can pick up.

For further explanations about $apply have a look into this blog post: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but what you are doing here is that you have updated the var manually, if you have 10 such vars you would have to do this updation 10 times.Not a good approach. I would like to update all the 10 vars with one generic code

Comment: I don't really understand your use case, but my example is the angular way of separating the view from the controller and the model. If you want to change your model (aka some javascript objects) you have to update them manually. How complicated that is, is up to you, you can define a model object in many different ways.